# Application in Unity using Vuforia shows only a green screen and doesn't show the camera

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I create a simple imageTarget application in Unity using Vuforia, however when I open it in my Android phone (Xiomi Redmi Note 11 pro 5G -  Android 12 SDQ1.211006.001- MUI 13.07) it only shows a green screen (see below).  I already give all the corresponding permission. I tried with another Android phone (SAMSUNG GALAXY A51-ANDROID 13-ONE UI 5.1) and it works properly. Does someone know what could be the error?
I'm using Unity version 2022.3.9f1. The minimal API level is Android Oreo 8.0. The Vuforia version is 10.17.4.

[image: Green Screen]

[image: Pyoyect elements]

I tried to change the minimal API level to 31 and 32, but it didn't solve anything.
I tried to change the Target API Level to 31,32, 34, and automatic (highest installed) and it didn't solve the green screen.

Comment: Are "google services for ar" installed on the device?

Comment: Yes, it is. There are no updates nor for that app either for the device's software.

Comment: Which rendering pipeline and Graphics API are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i had, with xiomi poco 5 pro, but solved. You need delete google serveces for ar.

Comment: removing google services for AR might fix the rendering issue but some Vuforia-Engine features need these services to function properly. See here https://library.vuforia.com/environments/vuforia-fusion